# BGP Route installed in routing table seen as valid but not as best

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp

I have BGP running between two routers.

When i run "show ip bgp vpnv4 neighbors 1.1.1.1 received-routes", I see the advertised routes from the neighbor as "valid (*)", not "best (>)" :

```
WAN01#sh ip bgp vpnv4 neighbors 1.1.1.1 received-routes
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *   192.168.1.0/24      1.1.1.1                             0 1 2 3 4 ?
 *   192.168.2.0/24      1.1.1.1                             0 1 2 3 4 i     
 *   192.168.3.0/24      1.1.1.1                             0 1 2 3 i
 *   192.168.4.0/24      1.1.1.1                             0 1 2 3 4 ?
```

The list goes on, all my 325 routes are valid, but not best.

However, they are actually installed in my global routing table :

```
WAN01#sh ip route bgp

B        192.168.1.0/24 [20/0] via 1.1.1.1, 1w4d
B        192.168.2.0/24 [20/0] via 1.1.1.1, 1w4d
B        192.168.3.0/24 [20/0] via 1.1.1.1, 1w4d
B        192.168.4.0/24 [20/0] via 1.1.1.1, 4d09h
```

How can I explain this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `show ip bgp vpnv4 neighbors 1.1.1.1 received-routes` shows all routes received from the neighbor before routing policies are applied (and as such doesn't show best-path information). To see which routes are **accepted** and possibly installed use the `show ip bgp vpnv4 neighbors 1.1.1.1 routes` command.

Also the `received-routes` command is only available if `soft-reconfiguration` is configured for the neighbor.